# Rank a subset of a column matching specific values of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to rank based on the blocksize condition, I don't want it ranking everything against everything else but only blocksizes that match.

For example:

```
  A             B            C         D
**Server     Block Size    Score      Rank** 
 SRV1          4k            200       2
 SRV1          4k            200       2
 SRV1          8k            100       5
 SRV1          8k            120       4
 SRV2          4k            180       3
 SRV2          4k            130       5
 SRV2          8k            200       3
 SRV3          4k            140       4
 SRV3          4k            220       1
 SRV3          8k            300       2
 SRV3          8k            500       1
```

I've tried the COUNTIF function and SMALL function and nothing seems to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ranking is not very clear, which columns are your grouping, and which column is the rank based on?

Comment: The real question is whether SRV2, 4k, 180 should be ranked **3** or **4**. If 4, then this is easy; if 3 then getting rid of the additional placement added by 2×SRV1, 4k, 200 is a real pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-function-6A2FC49D-1831-4A03-9D8C-C279CF99F723) does not respond well to standard array formula exclusion methods commonly used to apply criteria to standard functions.

Essentially, a RANK can be expressed as a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) like `=COUNTIF(A:A, ">"&A1)+1`. Additional conditions can easily be added by changing to a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

[image: rankif]

The formula in D2 is,

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$12, B2, C$2:C$12, ">"&C2)+1
```

Fill down as necessary.

These results differ from your sample in that SRV2, 4k, 180 is ranked 4<sup>th</sup> not 3<sup>rd</sup> due to the duplicate SRV1, 4k, 200 values.

However, if duplicates are to be discounted from the ranking index this has to be adjusted for any values subsequent to the duplicates will have their RANK numbers artificially raised.

[image: RankIf_w_duplicates]

The formula in D2 is now a bit more complicated as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B$2:B$12=B2)*(C$2:C$12>=C2))/(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$12, B2, C$2:C$12, C$2:C$12&"")+(B$2:B$12<>B2)))
```

Fill down as necessary. Note that the adjusted ranking for SRV2, 4k, 180 is now 3<sup>rd</sup>.

---

¹ <sub>The [RANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-function-6A2FC49D-1831-4A03-9D8C-C279CF99F723) function has been largely superceded by the [RANK.EQ](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/RANK-EQ-function-284858CE-8EF6-450E-B662-26245BE04A40) and [RANK.AVG](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/RANK-AVG-function-BD406A6F-EB38-4D73-AA8E-6D1C3C72E83A) functions available since XL2010.</sub>

Comment: You totally nailed it with COUNTIFS!  Thanks!  Not sure why I couldn't wrap my brain around that command but with your example it finally clicked!